# Canadian visitor visa online application fee payment

Tags: visas, canada

I am going to apply for an online Canadian visitor visa. 
Can I fill and complete the application form and pay the application fee later?

Can I login several times to the online application form? or the applicants should fill the online visa application form at their first login?

thank you